rsync --no-perms sometimes ignores umask?
I am trying to understand how rsync --no-perms behaves when copying files from a remote samba share to a local file system.
According to the rsync man page:

When the -p, --perms option is off: New files get their "normal"
permission bits set to the source file's permissions masked with the
receiving directory's default permissions (either the receiving
process's umask, or the permissions specified via the destination
directory's default ACL), and their special permission bits disabled
except in the case where a new directory inherits a setgid bit from
its parent directory.

I am using autofs to cifs mount a Samba Share on another machine like this:
/media/ubuntu -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/home/root/creds,iocharset=utf8 ://192.168.1.34/4TB1

When I list a particular file in that share it looks like this:
root@zoro:/media/hdd# ls -l "/media/ubuntu/movie/4tb1file.txt"
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Oct 21 21:59 /media/ubuntu/movie/4tb1file.txt

And when I straight-away run the mount command I can see all the cifs options being used to mount that share:
/etc/auto.network on /media/ubuntu type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=5019,timeout=5,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
//192.168.1.34/4TB1 on /media/ubuntu type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.02,sec=ntlmssp,cache=strict,username=4tb1,domain=WORKGROUP,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.34,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)

The umask on the machine that rsync is run from is 0022:
root@zoro:/media/hdd# umask
0022

If I run this rsync command:
root@zoro:/media/hdd# rsync -itrvv --no-perms "/media/ubuntu/movie/4tb1file.txt" /media/hdd

These are the permissions the file has after the transfer:
root@zoro:/media/hdd# ls -l 4tb1file.txt 
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Oct 21 21:59 4tb1file.txt

Why are the permissions the same? The permissions of the file in the share are 755. I was expecting 755 - 022 = 733 (rwx-wx-wx) but instead it is still (rwxr-xr-x). Except I think that is not possible because umask cannot give permissions, by setting the write bit, only take them away.
If instead I switch my local umask to 0044 then I found that indeed a file with source permissions of 755 (rwxr-xr-x) becomes 711 (rwx--x--x) after copying with rsync --no-perms ...
So is that the answer then? If a file has source permissions (in a samba share) of 755 (rwxr-xr-x) and the local umask is 022 then the permissions remain unchanged after a rsync --no-perms ... file transfer? But why?
I don't understand how the umask combines with the source file permissions to determine  file permissions after the transfer from a Samba share to the local file system.
Any help much appreciated.

umask performs bitwise AND with the bitwise complement (~) of the umask. The bitwise complement of 022 is 755. 755 & ~022 = 755 & 755 = 755. The bitwise complement of 044 is 733, 755 & ~044 = 755 & 733 = 711.

Thank you. If you want to make this as an answer I will accept it. Although I think an explanation with permissions expressed in symbolic form r w x is easier to understand. For instance it took me a while to understand why 755 & 733 = 711.
